# Test certificate not trusted

Tags: vsto, clickonce, code-signing

I develop VSTO solutions for Word and Excel.
Since yesterday, for no apparent reason, I am now unable to debug any of my solutions. I face the same symptoms even when I try to debug a new blank VSTO project.

When the add-in launches (typically at Excel or Word startup), the following shows up:

> System.Security.SecurityException: Customized functionality in this
>   application will not work because the certificate used to sign the
>   deployment manifest for ExcelAddIn1 or its location is not trusted.
>   Contact your administrator for further assistance.

[image]

This happens with both Word and Excel. I debug from Visual Studio 2017, under Windows 10 and Office 365 (click-to-run version). Is this a problem with VS2017 not properly registering the test certificate? or maybe a problem with my Windows configuration (certificates inclusion list, etc)?

### UPDATE

Updating and repairing Visual Studio 2017 did not have any effect.
Installing VS2019 and testing with new blank Excel VSTO Add-in did not have any effect.
Publishing that blank add-in using an EV Code signing certificate (from Sectigo, still valid and used many times in the past) does also produce the same problem.

I now suspect this might be due to the deployment manifest zoning. How can I investigate what is the registered location for the manifest, and what is its "effective" location? So that I can verify if both match.

Comment: Are you using a different certificate to sign your addin? Did the certificate expire?

Comment: I'd also check to see if your IT department applied a group policy.

Comment: This is not for production, this is for testing. Certificates did not expire but I clicked "Create Test Certificate" in the ClickOnce manifest section of the project properties. I have this problem with 3 different solutions which have nothing to do with each other; the problem also happens if I create a new blank project. No IT department, we are a startup (and have a release due for 31/12.. !). Maybe a Windows update?
I will try to install VS2019 and see if the problem remains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The registry keys were set to the settings as described here: [Disable the inclusion list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/how-to-configure-inclusion-list-security?view=vs-2019#disable-the-inclusion-list).

Changing these setting to [Enable the Inclusion list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/how-to-configure-inclusion-list-security?view=vs-2019#enable-the-inclusion-list) did fix my problem.

The reasons why this got changed do still remain a great mystery... Windows update?

Answer (score 5):

Try to Install your Certificate into:

1. Trusted Publishers Store (Current User).
2. Trusted Root Certification Authorities Store (Current User).

Go to Visual Studio, open *Project Properties*, choose *Signing*, hit *Select form Store...*. Hit *Click here to view certificate properties* and then *Install Certificate*. Choose Current User, then *Place all certificates in the following store*, browse ***Trusted Publishers***, hit *OK*, and *Finish*. Repeat the above for the ***Trusted Root Certification Authorities*** store.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Once the installation is completed, rebuild your project.

Comment: Thanks Pawel. As you might have seen from my answer to my own question, for some reason the trust settings had been changed. It happened again a few weeks ago; no idea why..

Comment: this must be a Windows update. I have my inclusion list disabled, too (registry). But the solution I've described works regardless of what has been set in the TrustManager\PromptingLevel key.

Comment: Yes it probably does. I'd say it's more a patch rather than a cure, since I never set my trust settings to Trusted Publishers Only, and Ms keeps resetting these settings..